Is there a formal noun equivalent for "twofer"?
According to Collins (mirror):

noun. Informal. A pair of (theater tickets, phonograph records, etc.) sold for, or approximately for, the price of one

Is there a formal noun equivalent for "twofer"?

You want to know how to talk about a 50% discount? Two for the price of one? Those are normal in formal and casual talk.

An informal UK one is 'BOGOF' - Buy One, Get One Free.

'Twofer' is shortened slang for "two for one", meaning you will receive two of something for the price of one.
It is not the same as a 'half-price' offer, or '50% off', because you cannot buy one ticket at a discounted price; you have to buy one at full price in order to get the second free. The other common term for this is "buy one get one free", which is informally shortened to the initialism BOGOF, and even more informally pronounced as an acronym (which is done for comic effect in the UK because it sounds like the colloquial British English expression "bog off" meaning 'go away').
Occasionally you might hear other names for these deals, such as "Two-for-One Special" or "Double Deal", which a promoter might choose to make their offer stand out. But the obvious and non-informal equivalent to "twofer" has to be the non-shortened "two for one", or "two for the price of one".

In the U.S., it's shortened to BOGO.

The more formal word combination would be simply "half-price"  but that is considered adjective usage rather than noun.
But if we separate the two words then it is counted as a noun!
"My tickets are half price" is equal to "My tickets are a twofer".
So having been corrected three times I will have to now say "2 nouns fer the price of 1" is.
"My tickets are a half price conditional offer" is equal to "My tickets are a twofer"

My tickets are twofer, no. a twofer. Anyway, that only in this case and for tickets.

@Lambie ok a point noted

Half price isn't the same as two for one. If it is half price, you could go alone and pay half. Two for one means someone has to pay full price in order to get a second person free.
